# I'm using the material design wpf library. how can I make the tooltip black?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I need to make the textbox completely black, but no matter how hard I try I can't make the tooltip black. How do I make it black?

[image]

I did a lot of research on how to make the textbox completely black and I almost got it. I did everything but the tooltip.

Comment: What do you mean by making it black? The text above or the line below? There is MaterialDesign Dark Theme, you can activate it.

Comment: @Tili: What "tooltip" are you referring to? Please include a code sample of your issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`ToolTip` styling in WPF pretty described at [official MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/tooltip-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

As minimalistic example you can use that one (**XAML**):

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="YourCustomFontIfNeeded" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BF1D1D1D"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
</Style>

<!-- ... -->

<Grid Background="#FFAFAFAF">
    <Button 
      Content="Press Me" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
      Width="200" 
      Height="48"
      FontSize="24" 
      ToolTip="Use LEFT mouse button to press, ok?"/>
</Grid>
```

Which will give you that look:
[image: ToolTip]